# Setter vs. Event

Tags: c#, events, delegates, unity-game-engine, setter

I'm currently doing a game in Unity. Imagen the following: You have a playfield consisting of 4x4 fields, on each field you can put a card. You play against an enemy. Each card does something. (Think of Magic: The Gathering)

In my Game, I have a class GameMaster which holds everything together and also does the main calculations. I also have a basic class "Card".

If I use a card, I need to pass the Info of what this card is doing to the GameMaster. How would you do the connection between the two? The data needs to be passed on the OnMouseDown()  event.

I would use a setter. So on the OnMouseDown() Event I'd call GameMaster.AddCard(cardData);

other said to me, I should use Events. I understand that events are more generic, they are nice for things like OnMouseDown(); OnClose(); etc. Thing which can be used everywhere and you can't predict from where they are going to be called. THey said, my code is more decoupled by using events. I kind of doubt it, since the relationship never changes. It's part of my game mechanics.

Then, someone said, "how would you test it?" and this is true. With events, testing is probably easier.

So, the question is: When not doing TDD, whats better? When using TDD, whats better?

Also, the things a card do is rather complex and really vary. So I though of doing several function like DoublePoints(); DoubleTime(); MakeSpecialMOveXYZ(); etc. these functions really vary from card to card. Is it okay, to just pass delegates of them from my Card-Class to my GameMaster-Card? (Via setter or event)

Comment: `Also, the things a card do is rather complex and really vary.... `this is a separate topic, please open a new question for it.

Comment: I think this question should be moved to gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

In your situation I'd use setters. Events are more the way to go in real-time/async processes.

> They said, my code is more decoupled by using events.

It all depends on the implementation. Both methods can produce decoupled code.

> With events, testing is probably easier.

I disagree, but then again, I'm no QA expert.